# MVVM does not receive message

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, mvvm-light

I am using mvvm light on my project. For communication between view, I am using GalaSoft.MvvmLight.Messaging.Messenger but it does not work as expected.
The code below:
Register a messenger

```
GalaMessenger.Default.Register<ServerNewMessenger>(ServiceLocator.Current.GetInstance<ServerNewViewModel>(), (msg) =>
            {
                Debug.Write("Click");
            });
```

Send messenger to receiver

```
Messenger.Default.Send<ServerNewMessenger>(newItem, ServiceLocator.Current.GetInstance<ServerNewViewModel>());
```

I never receive the message. But when I remove the recipient by the send method:

```
Messenger.Default.Send<ServerNewMessenger>(newItem);
```

Then it works fine. Why?

Comment: It's very important to initialize class/function which holds Default.Register before the Default.Send. It can be your problem. Check it.

Comment: Yes I did execute Default.Register before Default.Send.

Comment: Does the call to `GetInstance` return a different instance on each call?

Comment: Yes, I validate with the method `GetHashCode()` and it shows me the same code, that means it points to the same object.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're confused about the overloads of `Register` and `Send`.  In your second sample, you're using this overload of `Send`:

```
void Send<TMessage>(TMessage message, object token);
```

Since you're sending a message with a particular *token*, only those that called `Register` with that same token will receive the message.  In your first example, you're using this overload of `Register`:

```
void Register<TMessage>(object recipient, Action<TMessage> action);
```

You are specifying no token, so your object will not receive it.

If really do you want to send this message to *just* your `ServerNewViewModel`, use a unique token like a `GUID` or some string that you make up:

```
string token = "YourServerViewModelToken";
var serverNewViewModel = ServiceLocator.Current.GetInstance<ServerNewViewModel>();
GalaMessenger.Default.Register<ServerNewMessenger>(serverNewViewModel, token, (msg) =>
    {
        Debug.Write("Click");
    });
```

Then when you send it, use the same token:

```
string token = "YourServerViewModelToken";
Messenger.Default.Send<ServerNewMessenger>(newItem, token);
```